# How to change the datatype of column and add foreign key in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, sqldatatypes

I have a `user` table and `userInvoice` table. Now I have `userId` as `varchar(150)` in `userInvoice`. I need to change the datatype to `bigint` and make this column a foreign key to the `user` table.

How I can do it in an `alter` query?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's for SQL-server @marc_s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change datatype. You may find this link for more info [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

```
 ALTER TABLE userInvoice ALTER COLUMN UserId BIGINT
```

For foreign key. You may find this link for more info [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE userInvoice 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES USER(USERID);
```

Note: Be careful before alter column as data may get lost if it is not in supported format.